# Tengo un select que quiero validar

Tags: javascript, html, validación

Tengo el siguiente código que me permite activar o desactivar un campo de texto dependiendo de la opción que se seleccione en el Select:

```js
(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Motivo_TrasladoActivo<?=$ta+1?>").on('change',function()  {
            $("#Motivo_TrasladoActivo<?=$ta+1?> option:selected").each(function () {
                var valor=$(this).val();
                //alert(valor);
                if ($(this).val() === "6") {
                    $("#Otro_Motivo_TrasladoActivo<?=$ta+1?>").prop("disabled", false);
                } else {
                    $("#Otro_Motivo_TrasladoActivo<?=$ta+1?>").prop("disabled", true);
                    $("#Otro_Motivo_TrasladoActivo<?=$ta+1?>").val('');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

ahora el detalle es que quiero validar que si han seleccionado la opción 6 que habilita el campo de texto este no vaya vacío,  ahora tengo este código que me permite validar que efectivamente el campo no este vacío.

```js
if($("#Otro_Motivo_TrasladoActivo<?=$ta+1?>").val() == ""){
            swal.fire("Si selecciono OTRO MOTIVO favor de completar este campo.","Haga clic en OK para Cerrar","error");
            $("#Otro_Motivo_TrasladoActivo<?=$ta+1?>").focus(); // Esta función coloca el foco en el campo de texto.
            return false;
        }
```

lo cual me valida digamos correctamente cuando se elige la opción 6,  pero ahora el problema es que si regreso el selector a otra opción la que sea no importa cual se seleccione se queda el mensaje de error que no se ha completado el campo. Y solo seleccionando nuevamente la opción 6 y escribiendo algo deja de enviar el mensaje de error.

Me quede sin idea de como resolver esto.

Se agradece cualquier comentario que me ayude a resolver este detalle.

Saludos

Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No necesitas un ciclo para recorrer las opciones, cuando haya un cambio en el *select*, tomas el valor y comparas para habilitar o deshabilitar el otro campo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Motivo_TrasladoActivo<?=$ta+1?>").on('change', function() {
        // No necesitas un ciclo, tomas directamente el valor
        let valor = $(this).val();
        if ($(this).val() === "6") {
            $("#Otro_Motivo_TrasladoActivo<?=$ta+1?>").prop("disabled", false);
        } else {
            $("#Otro_Motivo_TrasladoActivo<?=$ta+1?>").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#Otro_Motivo_TrasladoActivo<?=$ta+1?>").val('');
        }
    });
});
```

Luego, para hacer la validación solo revisa que no está deshabilitado:

```
if($("#Otro_Motivo_TrasladoActivo<?=$ta+1?>").prop('disabled') === false) {
    if($("#Otro_Motivo_TrasladoActivo<?=$ta+1?>").val() == ""){
        swal.fire("Si selecciono OTRO MOTIVO favor de completar este campo.","Haga clic en OK para Cerrar","error");
        $("#Otro_Motivo_TrasladoActivo<?=$ta+1?>").focus(); // Esta función coloca el foco en el campo de texto.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Podrías usar `if(!$(elemento).prop('disabled'))` e, incluso, tener las dos condiciones en un solo `if`, pero dejé el código así solo para que sea más legible.

Comment: :O  a que caray ya había intentado eso pero al revés y no me había funcionado, quería validar en la validación que se seleccionara la opción 6 y que no fuera en blanco o vacío  el campo de texto pero no me funciono, y ahora asi tal cual lo expresas me funciona correctamente cuando no se ha seleccionado la opcion 6 o retornas de la opcion 6 a otra.  Saludos Gracias!!!!

Comment: ahora a revisar todas las validaciones que tengo :)  Buen día!!!.  Deja voy a comer... Saludos desde Fresilandia :)